# Pass file name to build script in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have the next configuration for a build system in PhpStorm:

[image: Build configuration]

And it works ok, but I have a problem... my build script needs to receive the name of the file I'm running it on, so, if I build a PHP file, it will run phpcs on it, but if I'm building a CSS or JS file, it will run gulp... with Sublime Text that is possible, is it possible with PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no macros support for Run/Debug Configurations -- they are made so they do not depend on a context (currently opened file in editor). In other words -- they are pretty static and all file names/paths are basically hard coded.

---

For what you are describing (build script).. you need to use [External Tools](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) functionality (which can have all of that and made specifically for such tasks). Once created, you can assign custom shortcut to any External Tools entry (check `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` for that) so it's more convenient to use it.

If you want such script to be called on every file save automatically -- then use [File Watchers](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm) -- pretty much external tools that will be called for you automatically (once per each file modified).

---

Since you are doing this for a build script -- maybe you should try to use dedicated (and therefore more appropriate in general) tools? For example: Gulp / Grunt .. or even [Phing](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Phing+Support+in+PhpStorm).

Answer (score 1):

Create external tool:
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/external-tools.html

You can assign hotkey to execute your build command.

[image]